# How to fully disassemble Python source

Tags: python, python-2.7, disassembly

I have been playing with the `dis` library to disassemble some Python source code, but I see that this does not recurse into functions or classes:

```
import dis

source_py = "test.py"

with open(source_py) as f_source:
    source_code = f_source.read()

byte_code = compile(source_code, source_py, "exec")
dis.dis(byte_code)
```

All I see are entries such as:

```
 54         456 LOAD_CONST              63 (<code object foo at 022C9458, file "test.py", line 54>)
            459 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
            462 STORE_NAME              20 (foo)
```

If the source file had a function `foo()`, I could obviously add something like the following to the sourcefile:

```
dis.dis(foo)
```

I cannot figure out how to do this without changing the source file and executing it. I would like to be able to extract the pertinent bytes from the compiled `byte_code` and pass them to `dis.dis()`.

```
def sub_byte_code(byte_code, function_or_class_name):
    sub_byte_code = xxxxxx
    dis.dis(sub_byte_code)
```

I have considered wrapping the source code and executing `dis.dis()` as follows but I do not wish to execute the script:

```
source_code_dis = "import dis\n%s\ndis.dis(foo)\n" % (source_code)
exec(source_code_dis)
```

Is there perhaps a trick to calling it? e.g. `dis.dis(byte_code, recurse=True)`

Comment: Actually it is doing the entire file - look for BUILD_CLASS or MAKE_FUNCTION directives

Comment: I do see those function names, but no byte code for them. Just LOAD_CONST 63 (<code object foo at 022C9458, file "tes.py", line 54>)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Import the file as a module and call `dis.dis()` on that **module** (rather than the individual functions).

```
import dis
import test

dis.dis(test)
```

You can also do this from the command-line:

```
python -m dis test.py
```

Quoting from the [documentation for `dis.dis`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#dis.dis):

> For a module, it disassembles all functions.

**Edit**: As of python 3.7, `dis.dis` is recursive.

Comment: Excellent, worked perfectly. I had spotted that in the docs but for some reason hadn't thought to use `import`.

Comment: The first approach works, but the `python -m dis test.py` doesn't. It disassembles only the first level of the source code, without recursion. All functions appears as code objects, like `(<code object my_func at 0x7f83f5ae18a0, file "source.py", line 17>`. My Python version is `3.6.7`.

Comment: With the in-code approach, top-level module code will not be disassembled because it has no representation in the `module` object. This means that you cannot see e.g. the content of code guarded by `if __name__ == '__main__':`. In particular, `dis.dis(this)` will give an empty result.

Answer (score 11):

Late answer but I would have been glad to find it when needed. If you want to fully disassemble a script with functions ***without importing it***, you have to implement the sub_byte_code function mentioned in the question. This is done by scanning byte_code.co_consts to find types.CodeType literals.

The following completes the script from the question:

```
import dis
import types

source_py = "test.py"

with open(source_py) as f_source:
    source_code = f_source.read()

byte_code = compile(source_code, source_py, "exec")
dis.dis(byte_code)

for x in byte_code.co_consts:
    if isinstance(x, types.CodeType):
        sub_byte_code = x
        func_name = sub_byte_code.co_name
        print('\nDisassembly of %s:' % func_name)
        dis.dis(sub_byte_code)
```

And the result will be something like that:

```
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object foo at 0x02CB99C0, file "test.py", line 1>)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('foo')
              4 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 STORE_NAME               0 (foo)

  4           8 LOAD_NAME                0 (foo)
             10 LOAD_CONST               2 (42)
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             14 STORE_NAME               1 (x)
             16 LOAD_CONST               3 (None)
             18 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of foo:
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
              2 UNARY_NEGATIVE
              4 RETURN_VALUE
```

Edit: starting from python 3.7, dis.dis disassembles functions and does this recursively. dis.dis has a `depth` additional argument to control the depth of function definitions to be disassembled.

Comment: Actually it is the only valid answer!
Importing would loose all the global module code that disappears when you use the imported module.